# SDL OpenGL window not responding, transparent

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, glew

The SDL window that I have created with an OpenGL context has problems:

1. It's transparent, you can see the console behind it. As you can see from the code below, I just wrote something to display red to the screen.
2. It doesn't respond to anything. As soon as I hover my mouse over the screen, the loading cursor appears, and clicking does nothing.

```
#define main SDL_main
#include "stdafx.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    bool quit = false;

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 0);

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0) {
        SDL_Quit( );
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Window* window = NULL;
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("SandVox", 100, 100, 600, 400, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    if (!window) {
        std::cout << "Unable to create window" << std::endl;
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        return 0;
    }

    SDL_GLContext glcontext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(window, glcontext);
    glewInit( );

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);

    SDL_Renderer* render = NULL;
    render = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    SDL_Event *mainEvent = NULL;
    mainEvent = new SDL_Event( );

    while (!quit && mainEvent->type != SDL_QUIT) ;
    {
        SDL_PollEvent(mainEvent);
        /*
           SDL_RenderClear(render);
           SDL_RenderPresent(render);
         */
        glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
    }


    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(glcontext);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(render);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    delete mainEvent;
    SDL_Quit( );

    return 0;
}
```

stdafx.h doesn't have anything very exciting, just this:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL_mixer.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/GL.h>
#include <GL/glxew.h>
#include <GL/wglew.h>
#include <GL/GLU.h>
```

EDIT: To preempt a question people might have, yes, I have OpenGL 4.0 installed on my computer, I've checked :)

Comment: `SDL_GL_SetAttribute()`ing *after* you create a context doesn't really do anything.

Comment: I suggest you have a good look at your event loop `while` statement. There's a semicolon there, that doesn't belong. Pro-Tip: Use a tool like uncrustify to automatically format the indenting of your code; I did this to your code and due to the superfluous semicolon the "loops" opening brace ends up in a different line (you need K&R style indentation of course to get to see this).

Comment: datenwolf: Wow, that was clumsy! I did not see that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the pixel format properties ***after*** you create your context is pretty pointless. The pixel format of the default framebuffer is immutable once the context is created.

Move all your calls to `SDL_GL_SetAttribute (...)` so that they come before `SDL_GL_CreateContext(window)`.

The swap interval can be set at any time, but everything else in this block of code needs to be moved:

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);
```

Right now, you are probably getting a single-buffered pixel format. That does not jive well with modern window managers, which only update individual windows when you swap back/front buffers. Buffer swapping causes an implicit flush (whether or not it swaps buffers), so this problem is most likely due to a compositing window manager.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check to see if this works later, I have a linker error to fix first ;)

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I had the misconception that when you change the settings, it changes the for all existing glcontexts. I was wrong. Thanks very much for the answer.